# How to use "there is" after "there is no reason for"?

Tags: syntax

Consider the sentence:

> There is nothing after the credits.

How do I add that after "*There is no reason for*"?

> There is no reason for there being anything after the credits.
>
> There is no reason for there to be anything after the credits.

Are those correct? They both seem very convoluted, is there a simpler way to say that?

Edit: Those alternative are pretty specific to "after the credits" and don't really work for other situations. Could you also give alternatives for the following sentence?

> There is no reason for there being anything after death.

Comment: Native English speaker, and I don't know at all how to make that simpler :P

Comment: @Stormblessed Does that mean both are correct?

Comment: *There is no reason for anything after the credits* ?

Comment: "There is no reason for anything to be added after the credits"

Answer (score 1):

> Are those correct?

Yes, more or less.

> They both seem very convoluted, is there a simpler way to say that?

Here are a few options:
"There's no reason for anything to be shown after the credits are finished."
"There's no reason for anything to be shown after the credits."
"There's no reason for anything after the credits."

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the syntax behind the last one. To me it sounds like things after the credits have no sense, it almost implies there's something. Isn't it equivalent to "*After the credits, there's no reason for anything.*"?

Comment: Also, what would your options be if it was "*after death*" instead of "*after the credits*"?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat, the last one may be overly abbreviated, it depends on the context.  If it's already clear what's being discussed then you may omit words, otherwise they should be included.  
As far as death, now you are changing the question.  I would say there isn't a rule, but rather you should attempt to rewrite the sentence such that "there" isn't repeated. The rewrite may be different for each case.  "There's no reason to believe in an afterlife."